# How to set environment instead of .env files?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I made application on Symfony4 and successfully deployed by DeployBundle.

Now I have a problem.

Normally in local, the environment is stored in `.env` file, but on production, I need to set the environments in OS according to this [article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html').

But, how?? or if I set environment in OS itself like in `bash_profile`, is it impossible to maintain multiple Symfony4 projects at the same time??

I am familiar with Symfony2, capistrano and Parameters.yml

At that time I made new Parameters.yml in shared directly , but on Symfony4, how can I set server setting.

Could you give some indication??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common place would be in your virtual host configuration.

Example for Apache Web Server:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    # ...

    SetEnv APP_ENV prod
    SetEnv APP_DEBUG 0
    SetEnv APP_SECRET d815b8d0c26835bb7ba2a920ef1cbb0b

    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

See more:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html
- https://serverfault.com/questions/351696/how-do-you-set-server-specific-env-values-in-nginx
- https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/50739cd498d2ae5d2075e25528bf8751

Comment: Thank you very much. This could be copy and paste on each server. Honestly speaking, it is a bit more troublesome than copying parameters.yml though.